# can't change background color on metro controls

Tags: microsoft-metro

I'm using VS 2015 and I just put Metro controls in my Winform project. The problem I'm having is that I can't change the background color of any Metro control in the tool box. Maybe it's by design?

Any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

Ok... so I'm dumb :) All I had to do was set "UseCustomBackColor" to TRUE. Then I could change the background color. I'm just telling this in case someone is just getting started like me :)